# Unable to handle kernel null pointer dereference

Tags: usb, kernel

Okay, so this is one of various problems I'm having trying to get by RPI/ModelB working. Here are the steps I've followed and the errors I've run into.

1. Installed Arch on 4GB SD card following [this tutorial.](http://elinux.org/RPi_Easy_SD_Card_Setup#Using_the_Linux_command_line)

   Everything worked out fine.
2. Plugged in USB keybard, HDMI video, ethernet, SD, and power. It boots. I get this error first thing.

   > [ 2.388456] driver/rtc/hctosys.c: unable to open rtc device(rtc0)]

   I don't know if that matters though. The rest of the boot process goes fine up until this.

   > [FAILED] Failed to start Netcfg networking service for profile ethernet-eth0. See 'systemctl status netcfg@ethernet-eth0.service' for details.
3. Then I log in as root with password root. I try to manually do netcfg.

   ```
   # netcfg down ethernet-eth0
   ::ethernet-eth0 down   [DONE]
   # netcfg ethernet-eth0
   ::ethernet-eth0 up [DONE]
   #ping www.google.com
   ping: unkown host www.google.com
   ```

   I'm plugged into a dchp configured router with a tested working ethernet cable.
4. After a while of being booted (5-10 minutes) one of two things will happen.

   - My keyboard stops working and I get these errors.

> ```
> usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
> hub 1-1: unable to enumerate USB device on port 1
> ```

- Or my keyboard stops working and after a few minutes I get these errors.

> ```
> Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address 756e00dc
> pgd = c1798000
> *pgd=00000000
> Internal error: Oops: 5 [#1] PREEMPT ARM
> Entering kdb (current=0xc153c380, pid 107) Oops: (null)
> due to oops @ 0xc0393798
> Pid: 107, comm: rngd
> CPU 0 Not tainted (3.6.11-6-ARCH+ #1)
> PC is at smsc95xx_async_cmd_callback+0x30/0x44
> LR is at usb_hcd_giveback_urb+0x60/0xf4
> ```

and the error goes on.

Anyone have any idea what might be going on here? I've spent two days strait now trying to get this thing to work but it seems every time I get one thing to work, two more things go wrong.

Comment: Where did you get your power supply from? It sounds insufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should get a different keyboard (the simpler and cheaper the better) and/or different power supply. the power supply ought to be marked as 5V 2A (or more A, not V), 2A is the lowest minimum when your RasPi will work reasonably stable.

Comment: Sure enough, that was it. I should have known better than to pick any random cheap power supply.